# .htaccess redirect all sub directories to external url

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following htaccess rule on my domain to redirect one specific subdomain to a new domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

That gets me about 50% of the way. Now, what I actually want to do is redirect that specific subdomain and any of it's sub directories to the same external URL. So subdomain.domain.com/about would redirect to http://www.newdomain.com/something/something/ in all instances.

Also, the reason for this redirect is an SEO one, so is there anyway to alert search engines that this is a 301 redirect?

Thank in advance for any help!

Comment: So something like `subdomain.domain.com/about` to `www.newdomain.com/subdomain/about`?

Comment: Just change your flags to `[L,R=301]`

Comment: @Howlin No; the new url doesn't need to correlate to the old url at all. The sites are going from many pages, to just one page. So, I just need all previous links/directories to forward to one specific url.

Comment: Changing it to `R=301` will do it.

Comment: @Howlin Not sure if what I need is coming across. I don't need the segments to match up to the new domain. I just need any and all links from the old subdomain to forward to 1 specific URL.

Comment: I got it. Just needed to remove the $1. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, that works as well. If you want it to go to a specific page you can add it as the link instead of `http://www.newdomain.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/somelink [L,R=301]
```

It should redirect anything in the `subdomain.domain.com` (including directories) to `http://www.newdomain.com/somelink`

Comment: Works as expected! Thank you.